# Show that the sum of 2n + 1 consecutive integers is divisible by 2n + 1.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Base case: $n=1$. Picking $2n+1$ random numbers 5,6,7 we get $5+6+7=18$. So, $2(1)+1=3$ which indeed does divide 18. The base case holds. 
Let $n=k>=1$ and let $2k+1$ be true. We want to show $2(k+1)+1$ is true. So, $2(k+1)+1=(2k+2) +1$....

Now I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Your induction has two flaws: a minor one is that the base case is never established (you need to show this for all $3$ consecutive numbers, not one random case).  The larger issue is structural: you simply won't get anywhere trying to induct on $n$.  But you might induct on the starting value (e.g. prove it for $a,\ldots,a+2n$ starting with $a=0$ or $a=-n$).

Comment: This is a special case of [Wilson's theorem for groups.](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+wilson%27s+group) Use the involution (reflection) $\rm\: x\to -x\:$ to partition the sum into pairs (with sum $\rm\equiv 0\,\ (mod\ 2n\!+\!1)),\:$ along with the fixed-point $\equiv 0.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a$ be the starting number. Then the $2n+1$ consecutive numbers are
$$a,a+1,a+2,\ldots,a+2n$$
The sum of these number is 
$$S(a,n) = (2n+1)a + \dfrac{2n(2n+1)}2 = (2n+1)(a+n)$$
Clearly, $(2n+1) \mid S(a,n)$.

Comment: @blutuu: Two fundamental (hidden) results that Marvis used here are that $$\sum_{j=0}^ka=(k+1)a$$ and that $$\sum_{j=0}^kj=\frac{k(k+1)}2.$$ Look at those in the special case that $k=2n$.

Comment: In regards to the first result, that would come from something like $b|a$ is the same as $a=bq$, correct?

Answer (score 5):

For clarity, we start by taking $n=4$.

Look at the following $2n+1=9$ consecutive integers:
$$-4, \quad-3,\quad -2, \quad -1,\quad 0,\quad 1,\quad 2,\quad 3,\quad 4.$$

The sum of these is $0$, obviously divisible by $2n+1$.

Now any $9$ consecutive integers can be obtained by adding a suitable constant $b$, possibly negative, to each of the numbers above.

But that means their sum is $0$, incremented by $9b$. So their sum is a multiple of $9$.

**Exactly** the same argument works for general $2n+1$, except that we start with the nmbers $0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \dots, \pm(n-1)$, arranged in increasing order.

Answer (score 5):

A variation on Marvis answer: let $a$ be the middle number. So the numbers are

$$
a-n,\dots,a-2,a-1,a,a+1,a+2,\dots,a+n
$$

So their sum is clearly $(2n+1)a$ which is divisible by $2n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of a sequence of consecutive integers is the average of the sequence, which is also the average of the largest and smallest terms, times the number of terms in the sequence. If the smallest term of a sequence of length $2n+1$ is $k$, the largest is $k+2n$. The average is $k+n$. Thus, the sum is $(2n+1)(k+n)$, which is easily divisible by $2n+1$.